# Post a JSON object to server using PHP & Jquery

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object:

```
[{"song_id":"17382","title":" Revolution","song_viewed":"6","FK_genre_id":"11","artist_id":"190","artist_name":"Crematory","album_id":"1507","album_name":"Revolution"},{"song_id":"17377","title":"Reign Of Fear","song_viewed":"6","FK_genre_id":"11","artist_id":"190","artist_name":"Crematory","album_id":"1507","album_name":"Revolution"}]
```

And I want to post this object to server using Jquery.post

```
function postData(dataObj){
  $.post(url,{data:dataObj});
};
```

in my PHP, I decode this object

```
$dataObj = $_POST['data'];
$dataObj = json_decode($dataObj);

print_r($datObj);
```

but it looks like it doesn't work.

Anyone help me?

Comment: could you print out your dataObj before trying to decode it to see just what's in there ?

Comment: "it looks like it doesn't work" - what does that mean? It's not printing anything? It's printing something but it's wrong?

Comment: Also add any errors PHP might show.

Comment: also please print the actual js snippet that is supposed to call that postData() function.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly get any more information before posting it here? Is the script being called? Is the array not looking like what you'd like? It sounds like you're asking us to replicate your setup in order to do debugging for you which you could easily do yourself.